# Plot time series and cumulative sum on same graph Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have a pandas df similar to the following:

```
time        price
00:00:00      2
00:10:00      6
00:20:00      3
01:25:00      16
02:25:00      7
```

etc...

I would like to plot on the same graph:

- Time series as the variation of price as function of time
- Bar graph as the number of observations taken that hour. So for the previous example, at 01:00:00 we have a bar of height 3 since from (00:00:00 -> 01:00:00 we had 3 observations) and at 02:00:00 we have height 1.

I was able to transform the data to get the bar graph data as a separate df using (.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='H'))). Now I have 2 dfs and trying to plot them.

My data points are around 100K+, cleaned it from outliers.

Any pointers?

Comment: bar graph does not play well with time series, specially when mixed with lineplot.

Comment: How would do this? @quang